# apply name= and class to tag <pre>

Tags: jquery

the code for syntax highlighter is `<pre name="code" class="cpp">` but typing this is time consuming so using jquery I want to apply to each and every `<pre>` class which is cpp and name which is code ie `name="code"`

here's what I think you would do for adding the cpp class

```
<script>$("pre").addClass("cpp");</script>
```

but how do you apply a name value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

name is a attribute, use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
.attr('name','code')
```